# Why does my Windows Server 2019 say it is not connect to the Internet?

Tags: internet, windows-server

I have set up a Windows Active Directory Server 2019. When logged in to the console, the server displays the not connected to the Internet icon at the lower right corner of the screen in the task bar. However, I can browse the internet, download software, and have external connections to the server.

I am just concerned that something could come back to bite me that I have over looked.

Only one of my two Ethernet ports is connected.

Comment: Perhaps the message concerns the other Ethernet port.

Answer (score 1):

The Network Connectivity Status Indicator (NCSI) is set by allowing the PC to connect to a Microsoft server, as shown in the O&O *ShutUp10* screenshot below.

There might be a Windows Firewall rule, or a [Group Policy](https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/configuring-network-connectivity-status-indicator-ncsi-with-group-policy/) setting, to prohibit the server from contacting MS, or specifying a different server for the probe. If NCSI is important to you, check the Firewall and GPO to change the setting, perhaps specifying a corporate server probe IP, rather than Microsoft's. Otherwise, ignore the indicator.

[image: NCSI]